# django relation syntax comparison

Tags: python, django, syntax

given the following models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)

class Bar(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
```

are these different?:

```
Foo.bar.filter(date=...)
Foo.objects.filter(bar__date=...)
```

**if they are, how? If not, why do they both exist?**

Comment: Since the first one is not a valid query in django, and will return an error, then yes, there is a differnce

Comment: I took this from some preexisting code, but I just realized that the `foo.bar.filter` comes from traversing a relationship. I simplified it too much.

Comment: So uh... question answered?

Answer (score 1):

As @yuvi mentioned `Foo.bar.filter(date=...)` is invalid. Maybe the first query would be like:

```
Foo.bar.get_query_set().filter(date=...)
```

`Foo.bar.get_query_set()` will generate a query set for `bar` which is same as `Bar.objects.all()`. Thus these two are completely different.

`Foo.bar.filter` does not exists since `Foo.bar` exists to get description about the field.

Comment: I apologize for the invalid query, I tried to copy this from preexisting code I was reading, and did it incorrectly. My main question is that I see things along the lines of Foo.bar... and foo.objects.filter(bar__...) and I was wondering if there was a difference in the syntax